# getting an incorrect OutOfRange exception

Tags: c#, winforms

I seem to get an `OutOfRangeException` that states the following: "Index out of the table limit" (not exact translation, my VS is french), this is the relevant code:

```
pntrs = new int[Pntrnum];
for (int i = 0; i < Pntrnum; i++)
{
    stream.Position = Pntrstrt + i * 0x20;
    stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    pntrs[i] = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0);
}

Strs = new string[Pntrnum];
for (int i = 0; i < Pntrnum; i++)
{
    byte[] sttrings = new byte[pntrs[i + 1] - pntrs[i]];//the exception occures here !
    stream.Position = pntrs[i];
    stream.Read(sttrings, 0, sttrings.Length);
    Strs[i] = Encoding.GetEncoding("SHIFT-JIS").GetString(sttrings).Split('\0')[0].Replace("[FF00]", "/et").Replace("[FF41]", "t1/").Replace("[FF42]", "t2/").Replace("[FF43]", "t3/").Replace("[FF44]", "t4/").Replace("[FF45]", "t5/").Replace("[FF46]", "t6/").Replace("[FF47]", "t7/").Replace("[0a]", "\n");

    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new string[]
                {
                    i.ToString(),
                    pntrs[i].ToString("X"),
                    Strs[i],
                    Strs[i],
                });
    listView1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] {item});
}
```

am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: The issue is with `pntrs[i + 1]`. When pntrs is at the final index, you're adding `1` which would push it out of bounds.

Comment: `i + 1` will be outside the bounds of `pntrs`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the `OutOfRangeException` because of i + 1 in the following line:

```
byte[] sttrings = new byte[pntrs[i + 1] - pntrs[i]];
```

You can easily prevent this by the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Pntrnum - 1; i++)
{
    byte[] sttrings = new byte[pntrs[i + 1] - pntrs[i]];
    ...
}
```

This will prevent i + 1 from going out of the range.

Answer (score 4):

C# arrays are zero indexed; that is, the array indexes start at zero( in your case you have elemets from 0 to `Pntrnum-1` in `pntrs`), so when `i == Pntrnum - 1` `pntrs[i + 1]` try to access element outside the bounds of `pntrs`

Comment: but if i put the pntrnum - 1 on the 'for i' it will not get the last string from the text file.

Comment: describe what you're trying to achieve

Comment: well i have this file, containing pointers to text strings, so the pointer number is pntrnum is in the header of the file, the first part is to get all the pointers (pntrs), then after that get all the strings (strs) that are located by the pointers, if i put pntrnum - 1, it will not get the last string, but if i remove that - 1 part, it gives me the out of range, and i can't put [pntrs[i] - pntrs[i - 1] since it will give me the same out of range text.

Comment: @Omarrrio why you don't use `StreamReader` with it's `ReadLine()` method. And what does exactly pointers contains, I don't understand why do you need to subtract them.

Answer (score 4):

i+1 is problem at the last iteration of loop
supposse last index in 9
then it will try to fetch 10 that the problem